# Has there been a change to the `edit` link to comments so it isn't shown after the 5 min. timeout?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is a recent change on StackOverflow or if I'm just remembering wrong. I recall being able to `edit` a comment to reveal the actual comment and markdown after the 5 min. timeout in the past. This was important if I wanted to improve a comment but did not want to have to go though re-typing all the markdown. I could `edit` the comment, `cancel`, then `delete` the comment and paste the original containing the markdown into a new comment and edit to improve. Now I can't even find the `edit` after 5 minutes.

If this was a change, please consider rolling it back. It was helpful to be able to display the comment with markdown after the 5 minute timeout in order to improve the comment by copying/pasting in a new comment and deleting the original.

If there was no change here, disregard, I must be getting senile.

---

**Example Comment From Yesterday**

Here is an example comment from yesterday. When I hover over the normal place where `edit` should appear, the only option is to delete the comment. The `edit` option no longer appears client-side (I am using Firefox).

[image]

Comment: This only existed if you opened the page before the 5 minute time out. Are you saying that even if the edit link was there that it now gets hidden dynamically by clientside JavaScript?

Comment: If you are saying that then no repro for me. The screenshot shows the edit link for the comment above was still there after 8 minutes http://i.stack.imgur.com/WlxAc.png

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. I always remember being able to edit my comments, even 10 minutes later (I just couldn't save them -- but that allowed me to copy and improve the comment) Now the `edit` tag is completely hidden in my firefox browser after the 5 minute timeout. It simply no longer exists on the client side.

Comment: The problem to be solved is following the 5 min. timeout, if there is something that needs to change in a `properly` *formatted* `comment`, you cannot simply select the comment text and retain the formatting. Even though you cannot save changes, there is significant benefit to being able to `view comment source` to select the comment source so, if needed, the original can be deleted and a new comment made -- without having to reformat all `code`, *italics*, **bold**, [links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com), etc.. It would sure be nice to have.